# jQuery .empty() && .append() inexplicably failing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently working on the restaurant page jQuery challenge on The Odin Project and I have hit a quite inexplicable brick wall. The problem I am dealing with has to do with the click event listeners. Everytime I click one of the top links on my page, it will empty the body of all the contents and generate a new HTML structure, but it will only do this once for the first click, and will not do it for any subsequent clicks.

What is making this problem particularly frustrating is that I did not have to deal with this when I only had the click event listeners set up for the Home and Menu pages. When I only had these set up, I was able to easily cycle between both pages freely. But it was only when I added the event listener for the Contact page that I started to experience this problem. Even worse, the addition of the Contact event listener has seemed to “infect” my program, to where I can no longer cycle freely between the Home and Menu pages, even when I comment out the code for the Contact event listener!

This issue has really been grinding my gears, so I have been forced to turn to you my dear readers. Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix this problem? I would be eternally grateful to anyone willing to help. The HTML, CSS, and jQuery will be posted below

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  background-color: slategrey;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1%;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

#contact-info {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#content").append("<header><ul><li><a id='home' href='#'>Home</a>       
  <li><li><a id='menu' href='#'>Menu</a></li><li><a id='contact'>     
  href='#'>Contact</a></li></ul></header><img src='http://teaessare.com/wp-
  content/uploads/2012/05/compassion_vegan.jpg' class='img-responsive img- 
  thumbnail'></img><p>Come on down to the Vean Restaurant today! We serve  
  the best Vegan foods in town!</p>")

$("#home").on("click", function() {
  $("#content").empty();
   $("#content").append("<header><ul><li><a id='home' href='#'>Home</a>  
   </li><li><a id='menu' href='#'>Menu</a></li><li><a id='contact' 
   href='#'>Contact</a></li></ul></header><img src='http://teaessare.com/wp-
   content/uploads/2012/05/compassion_vegan.jpg' class='img-responsive img-
   thumbnail'></img><p>Come on down to the Vean Restaurant today! We serve    
   the best Vegan foods in town!</p>")
});

$("#menu").on("click", function() {
  $("#content").empty();
  $("#content").append("<header><ul><li><a id='home' href='#'>Home</a>  
  </li><li><a id='menu' href='#'>Menu</a></li><li><a id='contact'
  href'#'>Contact</a></li</ul></header><table><tr><td>Buddha's 
  Delight</td><td>A traditional dish eaten by Shaolin Monks. So good that 
  you just might pass out of existence</td></tr><tr><td>Vegetable 
  Korma</td><td>A spicy and aromatic dish. Eat this to obtain moksha.
  </td></tr><tr><td>Vegan Nachos</td><td>Simple, but gets the job done.</td>
  </tr><tr><td>Pad Thai</td><td>A tried and true Vegan dish. A medley of  to 
  strong flavors.</td></tr><tr><td>Vegan Sushi</td><td>A cruelty-free<td>An 
  alternative to a classic Japanese dish.</td></tr><tr><td>Loubyeh 
  B’zeit</td>exotic option for those who want to try something different.
  </td></tr></table>")
});

$("#contact").on("click", function() {
  $("#content").empty();
  $("#content").append("<header><ul><li><a href='#' id='home'>Home</a> 
  </li><li><a href='#' id='menu'>Menu</a></li><li><a href='#' 
  id='contact'>Contact</a></li></ul></header><div id='contact-info'<p>Phone
   Number: 000-000-0000</p><p>E-Mail: veganrestaurant@yoohoo.com</p><p>00000  
  Vegan Avenue, Vegan City, Vegania</p></div>")
});
});
```

Comment: See @adeneo's answer for the reason. As a side note, you could just use `.html('...')` instead of calling `.empty()` and `.append('...')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It makes the coder cleaner and more concise, which I like very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`empty()` and `append()` isn't failing, the click handler is because the elements don't exist when you attach the handler.

You need delegated event handlers when you keep replacing the content like that

Replace

```
$("#home").on("click", function() {....
```

with

```
$("#content").on("click", "#home", function() {
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I made the adjustment that you suggested and everything works fine now. I will be studying up on event delegation so that I can really cinch this into my brain. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexiusMeinong - you're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer if it worked

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to do that earlier. Thanks for the reminder.